# ViewPager with zoom imageView and imageLoader

Tags: android-viewpager

I want to implement a viewPager with it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch or ScaleImageView or other implementation of zoom image view...
My problem is that I use imageLoader to display the image:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(path,imageView);
```

I use it to display the images fast (maybe this is my problem and i can use something else..)

the result is that the image is not scaled, i want it to be "FIT CENTER".

when i set it to FIT CENTER by scale type i cannot zoom it, it must be MATRIX...

How can i do it? i searched a lot for the right answer..